# Call Direct3DInterop's function from CubeRenderer class Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, interop, c++-cx

I have a basic project from DirectX and XAML App (Windows Phone 8.0) template.

Is there a way to call a function in the interop class from the renderer class?

If yes, how?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a get accessor at global scope, or just pass a pointer/reference to your Direct3DInterop class into the CubeRenderer.

Here's a code sample of how to define a global get accessor

Direct3DInterop.h:

```
public ref class Direct3DInterop sealed
{
public:
    Direct3DInterop();
    // class methods
};

Direct3DInterop^ GetD3DInterop();
```

Direct3DInterop.cpp:

```
Direct3DInterop^ g_d3dInterop = nullptr;

Direct3DInterop^ GetD3DInterop()
{
    return g_d3dInterop;
}

Direct3DInterop::Direct3DInterop()
{
    g_d3dinterop = this;
}
```

Comment: No, as far as I know the interop is cpp (Direct3DInterop.cpp) I just want to get access to it from the renderer class which is also cpp(CubeRenderer.cpp). No C# method calls.

Comment: Thank you, finally I managed to call interop's function from the renderer. In order to work the global accessor way I had to add the #include "Direct3DInterop.h" into renderer's cpp file and optionally the namespace from the interop